# Hello world VR app

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I've view-master mattel VR headset, something similar to 
Google cardboard. But am not sure where to start 
for hello-world kind of app. Not even sure if I can use
google vr sdk

Comment: I am sure that simply googling this would have solved this. There are many tutorials out there!

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-google-cardboard-vr-app-in-unity/) you can read a full tutorial about that. You will need a head support and a smartphone compatible to make google cardboard works, so I believe you will have no problem. You will have to download unity plugin as it is described in this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Google VR dev kit. They have one for ios;

https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/